# how to test private Observable inside public method?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I am new with tests.

I have something like next code and wish to cover it with unitTests using the Mockito:

```
    public void doSomeJob(){
        //some code before
        getMvpView().execute(getObservable());
        //some code after
    }

    private Observable<Boolean> getObservable(){
        return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Boolean> e) throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                e.onNext(true);
                e.onComplete();
            }
        });
    }
```

so questions:

1. how correct write test for `getMvpView().execute(getObservable());` using Mokito?
2. how can i verify result of `getObservable()`?

Comment: Have private method with a annonymous class implementation doesn't look easy to test it, so, extract your ObservableOnSubscribe instance reference as a class field, to another factory class, create a method to fetch it or any kind or strategy to can mock it and test it easily.

Answer (score 0):

If your private method is not a part of the interface, i.e. cannot be reached from outside the class, it's not something you should test (presumably it's not, since it's private). Mockito in turn [doesn't provide mocking of private methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mockito-And-Private-Methods). Thereby you either need to change your interface (make this data available outside) or leave it without testing.

Comment: Erm... Of course you need to test private methods, normally you do so implicitly by calling the public methods that call these private methods. But in any case, of course these private methods should be covered by tests.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz are we talking about unit testing? I think the idea behind it is to test a class interaction, like how the interface of a class works. Tests should not be aware of any private implementation, and they don't care whether it's called or not - just checking public interface.

Comment: If the test doesn't cover the whole unit (in this case, class), it's not a complete test. What does a test help you that doesn't cover your private methods if the bug is in that private method?

Answer (score 0):

What you should test is the **effect** of calling the public methods of your class under test. If you do so you will be able to freely refactor the implementation details later, and your tests will still verify that your class works as expected.

I suppose that your code is part of a presenter implementation and the getMvpView() method returns a view interface:

```
public class MvpPresenterImpl {

    private MvpView view;

    public void doSomeJob(){
        //some code before
        getMvpView().execute(getObservable());
        //some code after
    }

    public void attachView(MvpView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    private MvpView getMvpView() {
        return view;
    }

    private Observable<Boolean> getObservable(){
        return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Boolean> e) throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                e.onNext(true);
                e.onComplete();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can test the effect of `doSomeJob()` like so:

```
public class MvpPresenterImplTest {

    private MvpPresenterImpl presenter;
    private MvpView mockView;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        // Create a mock view instance so that we can verify method calls on it
        mockView = mock(MvpView.class);

        // Create our object under test, and set it up with the mock view
        presenter = new MvpPresenterImpl();
        presenter.attachView(mockView);
    }

    @Test
    public void doSomeJob_callsExecuteOnViewWithCorrectObserver() throws Exception {

        // What we want to test is the effect of invoking a public method.
        presenter.doSomeJob();

        // Verify that the execute method has been called by your class 
        // under test, and save the parameter for later.
        ArgumentCaptor<Observable<Boolean>> paramCaptor = 
            ArgumentCaptor.<Observable<Boolean>>forClass((Class)Observable.class);
        verify(mockView).execute(paramCaptor.capture());

        // Get the actual observable that the execute method was called with.
        Observable<Boolean> param = paramCaptor.getValue();

        // Get a test observer so that we can check what our Observable emits 
        // (TestObserver is a built-in feature of RxJava, not Mockito.)
        TestObserver<Boolean> test = param.test();

        // Assert that the Observable behaves as expected
        test.assertComplete();
        test.assertResult(true);
    }
}
```